# View created rule for AdBlock+ Element Hiding Helper in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, adblock

How can I view the list rules that I have created for the AdBlock+ Element Hiding Helper extension in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you realise that AdBlock+ Element Hiding Helper has no connection to the official Adblock Plus extension for Chrome. Having said that, have you tried the `AB+ icon menu / Edit rules` option (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)?

[image]

Comment: when I click on that it only displays a small dialog box saying: "Please, edit styles"

Comment: There's just that message? Can you post a screenshot of the dialog?

Comment: here: http://s12.postimage.org/5r7300del/screenshot_16.jpg

Comment: I'm stumped, never seen that dialog and frankly, it doesn't make sense given the context. Of course, I've never used this extension either.